# fetch the list of location with a particular location as center and radius (say 50km) , using google location API

Tags: javascript

I need the list of locations (areas/subareas) in a particular city.

I thought, google api might be a possible option to fetch this. if i pass city's lat/long and radius then there must be some way to fetch the list of locations.

however i could not find any possible solution?

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Google Maps JavaScript API V3 can be a good solution for it. If you check [this website](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_responses), there is a similar example of it:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.search(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]); 
    }
  }
}
```

There it finds stores in a specific radius from Pyrmont. You can take a look at it documentation, change the type parameter (see [this list](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html)) for whatever you want and get its result in that `callback` function. After that, you could use those cities' info for your purpose.